# WPF Treeview and databinding a Directory Tree

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I'm trying to implement a Directory Tree View that also shows all the files in my MVVM project. My Folder and Files structure in the `Model` is like this:

```
public class UserDirectory
{
   private ObservableCollection<UserFile> files;
   private ObservableCollection<UserDirectory> subfolders;
   private String directoryPath;
   //public getters and setters...
}

public class UserFile
{
   private String filePath;
   private Category category; //Archive, Document, Exe, etc...
   //public getters and setters
}
```

I'd like to show them in a TreeView, but after reading [this very helpful Josh Smith article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode), and various other sources, I still don't know how to work it out with `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

**Possible solution**

I've figured out that maybe I have to create a specific type, like `Item`, that exists only for showing the name of the files and the directories,

```
public class Item
{
    private List<String> directories;
    private List<String> files;
}
```

but I'd like to reuse my class structure, because I need to show the `Category` data of the `UserFile`, for example.

**The question**

How can I show the files and the subfolders while maintening my current Data Structure?

[This is an example of what I want to reach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8YzM.jpg) (I'm sorry but image uploading isn't working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XAML

```
<TreeView
    ItemsSource="{Binding RootDirectoryItems}"
    >
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserDirectory}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserFile}">
            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

`RootDirectoryItems` is presumed to be a property of the viewmodel, something like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Object> RootDirectoryItems { get; } 
    = new ObservableCollection<object>();
```

In the C#, assume the presence of `INotifyPropertyChanged` boilerplate on all property setters. I added two properties to `UserDirectory`:

1. `Name`, a readonly property which returns just the name segment of `DirectoryPath`. If `DirectoryPath` may change at runtime, its setter should call `OnPropertyChanged("Name");`, so that bindings looking at the `Name` property will know they need to get the new value. `UserFile` gained a similar `Name` property, which comes with the same advice about raising `PropertyChanged` if that's a possibility.
2. `Items`: Again, a readonly property, and you should raise `PropertyChanged` appropriately if either of the constituent collections changes (handle `ICollectionChanged.CollectionChanged`, and do likewise in the setters if you have setters). Bindings don't care about the declared type of a property, so it just returns `System.Collections.IEnumerable` -- it could even return `object`, and the XAML wouldn't care. But let's be just specific enough, without being so specific as to encourage anybody in C# to try to use the property for anything.

If it were me, I'd almost certainly make `UserDirectory` and `UserFile` bare immutable "POCO" classes without `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and simply repopulate if anything changed on the disk. I might depart from immutability by giving `UserDirectory` a `FileWatcher` and having it repopulate itself, if I had some reason to expect directories to change a lot.

So here's the C#:

```
public class UserDirectory
{
    public ObservableCollection<UserFile> Files { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<UserFile>();
    public ObservableCollection<UserDirectory> Subfolders { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<UserDirectory>();

    //  Concat demands a non-null argument
    public IEnumerable Items { get { return Subfolders?.Cast<Object>().Concat(Files); } }

    public String DirectoryPath { get; set; }
    public String Name { get { return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(DirectoryPath); } }
}

public class UserFile
{
    public String FilePath { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public String Name { get { return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FilePath); } }
}
```

---

Your `Item` class isn't needed, because XAML works by "duck typing".

Here's a simpler variant that also works, because both `UserDirectory` and `UserFile` have a `Name` property, and `UserFile`'s missing `Items` property is quietly shrugged off.

```
    <TreeView
        ItemsSource="{Binding RootDirectoryItems}"
        >
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a very well written explanation, I only have a few doubts. 1) I don't understand the purpose of `RootDirectoryItems`, what should I put in here exactly? 2) Also, with `Subfolders?.Cast<Object>().Union(Files);` we're basically merging the `Subfolders` and `Files` lists into the `Items` list, right? Because I had the same idea but tried to put them in the ViewModel with a `CollectionContainer`, but didn't know how to move forward.

Comment: 1. `RootDirectoryItems` is the items you populate the root of the TreeView with. `UserDirectory` and maybe some `UserFile` too. How were you populating it before? 2. Yes, that produces a resulting enumeration of all the subfolders followed by all the files. You don't need anything fancy there -- just any old sequence of those objects for the TreeView to enumerate.

Comment: 1. I wasn't populating it before, actually. I have a `UserDirectory rootDirectory` property in my ViewModel that is given to a `Worker` class type to find its files and subfolders. Can I just return the `Items` of the `rootDirectory` in the `get` of `RootDirectoryItems`?

Comment: @RiccardoLomazzi Absolutely. Or make `RootDirectory` a public property and bind `ItemsSource="{Binding RootDirectory.Items}"`. Once you're writing code around enumerating directories into `UserDirectory` instances, it's clean and simple to just use a `UserDirectory` for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. I'm trying right now to implement it. It's hard to keep that POCO structure, I'll guess I'll just implement an OnPropertyChanged on the properties of UserFile and UserDirectory (yes, I'll need to modify their paths in the future). But that `FileWatcher` has my curiosity...